# Como adquirir permissão para gravar no registro do Windows via VB a chave HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: vb.net

Pessoal estou tentando gravar um registro dentro da `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM`
e o visual studio / visual basic não me deixa ter acesso. Diz que não tenho permissão para gravar meu registro.

Meu comando:

```
My.Computer.Registry.SetValue("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM", "1", &H1I, Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind.DWord)
```

O erro:

[image: System.UnauthorizedAccessException]

Obrigado a todos que puderem ajudar ; compartilharei o meu projeto aqui no final em agradecimento a toda a comunidade.

Comment: Não seria uma permissão de sistema? O Visual Studio não pode passar por cima das permissões do usuário que está executando o serviço.

Comment: Então eu apliquei o regedit a todos e mesmo assim não grava .
Doidera ; nunca vi isso .

Comment: Na pasta Current_user vai normal .

Comment: pow tentei de tudo aqui já @TiagoCésarOliveira .

Comment: Consegui@TiagoCésarOliveira era a permissão mais como eu coloco ela direta pelo visual basic ?
Porque não posso falar para o meu usuário simplismente ir lá num sei em que pasta e talz e aplicar a permissão ela teria que ser dada direta pelo VB .

Comment: @MauricioPeffoni essa é uma permissão do user do windows, não pode ser programaticamente setada...

Comment: Chute de um não-especialista na área: e se você rodar o seu executável (seu programa compilado) como administrador da máquina, ele grava?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A chave HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE só permite a gravação se o usuário logado no Windows for administrador, e no caso do UAC se o programa que está tentando modificar o valor tiver sido executado com permissões elevadas.

No geral não se deve fazer nenhuma mudança dentro de HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, qualquer configuração de programas por exemplo deveria ser salva no HKEY_CURRENT_USER

Comment: Entendo sua posição .
Até mesmo no Current user ele está me pedindo permissão e sou adm do usuário .

Comment: Fiz um teste e mudando para HKEY_CURRENT_USER ele gravou sem problemas usando o seu código. Só que não entendo o motivo de você querer gravar na chave "System", no geral não se deve usar nenhuma chave que não seja uma criada por você dentro da chave "Software".

Comment: Obrigado Leandro pela consideração; Existe algum método de adquirir direitos sobre a chave a de acesso ?
Um comando ou algo do tipo ? @Leandro Godoy Rosa